# Euclid’s Elements, Book 1, Definition 4 of a straight line

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

I’m very confused by Euclid’s definition 4 in Book 1 of a straight line

> 4. A straight line is a line which lies evenly with the points on itself

I’ve read elsewhere that Euclid’s axioms aren’t as complete / formally defined as in other texts.  But I’m curious if I’m simply reading this wrong.

By this definition, wouldn’t every line be a straight one? Do not all lines lie evenly with the points on themselves?

Comment: In The Wikipedia article [line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_(geometry)) it is stated "When geometry was first formalised by Euclid in the Elements, he defined a general line (straight or curved) to be "breadthless length" with a straight line being a line "which lies evenly with the points on itself"These definitions serve little purpose since they use terms which are not, themselves, defined. In fact, Euclid did not use these definitions in this work and probably included them just to make it clear to the reader what was being discussed."

Comment: Some scholars believe these definitions are spurious and were added to the text during Middle Ages.